# Why isn't row-gap working on the left grid?

Tags: html, css

I have two separate one-column grids side by side. The html layout is the same for both grids but in css the grid on the left is not showing row-gap on the webpage.

[image: 1]

```
html:

<div class="both-grids">
    <div class="show-grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">show 1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="movie-grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">movie 1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 5</div>
    </div>
</div>


css:

.both-grids {
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.show-grid-container, .movie-grid-container {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-rows: 40px 200px 200px 200px 200px;
    row-gap: 40px;
}

.movie-grid-container {
    padding-left: 80px;
    
}

.show-grid-container, .movie-grid-container > div {
    background-color: black;
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `> div` on `.show-grid-container` in the last piece of CSS

Answer (score 0):

```css
.both-grids {
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.show-grid-container, .movie-grid-container {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-rows: 40px 200px 200px 200px 200px;
    row-gap: 40px;
}

.movie-grid-container {
    padding-left: 80px;
    
}

.show-grid-container >div, .movie-grid-container >div {
    background-color: black;
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="both-grids">
    <div class="show-grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">show 1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">show 5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="movie-grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">movie 1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">movie 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use this in css
.show-grid-container >div, .movie-grid-container >div {}
instead of
yours -> .show-grid-container, .movie-grid-container > div {}